# MVC 5 Routing - parameters to a different page

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Not sure if I'm going about this the wrong way but I would like to have `mydomain/mycontroller/myaction` return one page and `mydomain/mycontroller/myaction/{id}` return a different page.

For example `mydomain.com/User/Services` would return a list of services, where as `mydomain.com/User/Services/2` would return just the service of the id (2 in this example).

This way the URL would appear logical to the end user, and if they so wished they could just enter an id and it would bring up the page of just that Service.

With the code below I get a non-optional parameter error if I don't make it `int?` as it forgoes the named `Services` ActionResult and tries to use the re-routed one.

Is this possible?

**Code**

Controller:

```
[Route("Services/{id}")]
        public ActionResult Service(int? id)
        {
            return View();
        }
        public ActionResult Services()
        {
            return View();
        }
```

RoutConfig:

```
routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Service",
                url: "{controller}/Services/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "User", action = "Service", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
```

Comment: Are you calling `mydomain.com/User/Services/2` (plural) or `mydomain.com/User/Service/2`? (the second would be correct). And why do you even have that route (the default route will handle it correctly). You certainly don't need 2 routes as per the answer you accepted and it would be crazy to do so.

Comment: I initially had it so it was `mydomain.com/User/Services` and `mydomain.com/User/Service/2` but the hierarchy wanted it changed as it was "more logical" to read for the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to define multiple routes

```
routes.MapRoute(name: "Services",//Service_withoutid
                url: "{controller}/Services",
                 defaults: new
                 {
                     controller = "User",
                     action = "Services",
                     // nothing 
                 }
);

routes.MapRoute("Service", //Service_withid
                url: "{controller}/Service/{id}",
                defaults: new
                 {
                     controller = "User",
                     action = "Service",
                     id = UrlParameter.Optional 
                 }
);
```

Comment: Thanks, trying to get this work now, should it not have defaults: in front of new?

Comment: Ah it was the names (`name = "has to be actionresult"`)that were screwing me up, cheers.